# How to Remove a task from Event Viewer

Tags: windows-server-2012, event-viewer

Just attached a task to a security (Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Security) event on Event Viewer, but now it seems not possible to change it or even remove it.

Does anyone knows where it could be?

Is a Windows Server system.

Thanks.
Gon Lou

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the solution.

Just need to navigate to this folder: 
*C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Event Viewer Tasks*
All the tasks appear there, just need to delete the ones desired.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Close task scheduler and open it with admin privileges. Expand task scheduler library and click on Event Viewer tasks. Your task should be there.